# Print + Input + Print en una misma línea

Tags: python-3.7, input, print

Soy nuevo programando en python y tengo una duda para un ejercicio que no logro resolver. Debo mostrar un print y, en la misma línea, a continuación del print, debo ingresar un input, tras lo cual nuevamente y en la misma línea, se muestra otro print.

El ejercicio sería:

`print ("Intento 1: ")`
`var_numero = int(input())`
`print(var_Dato1)`

Todo esto debería mostrarse en una única línea... no sé si esto es posible, pero es lo que se me pide hacer.

Les solicito vuestra ayuda por favor.

Muchas Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2):

- Si tienes `Python 3.6 o mayores` podrías utilizar [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python):

```
>>> print(f"My name is {input()}. How are u?")
Adrian
My name is Adrian. How are u?
```

- Sino, podrías utilizar [str.format()](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#option-2-strformat):

```
>>> print("My name is {name}. How are u?".format(name=input()))
Adrian
My name is Adrian. How are u?
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el punto-y-coma para separar dos instrucciones en la misma línea.

El ejercicio quedaría:

```
print ("Intento 1: "); var_numero = int(input()); print(var_numero)
```

Nada más

Comment: Igual es una tontería mi duda pero, ¿es lo mejor usar semicolons en Python aunque sean como un line terminator?

Comment: Por claridad visual, soy partidario de una instrucción por línea y evitar los semicolons. No aportan nada y sólo generan ruido.

Comment: Guay, guay. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

no comprendo bien de donde sale el var_Dato1, pero si quieres imprimir en una linea, y quieres que el input () que vas a ingresar este al lado de lo que imprimiste podrías usar:

```
var_numero = int (input ('El numero se ingresa en la misma linea'))
```

Esto hará que en la misma linea que dice 'Aqui va el texto', te pedirá que ingreses un numero entero, caso contrario si lo pusieras de la manera normal, el input () lo pediría en la linea siguiente como en este caso...

```
print ('El numero se ingresa en la linea de abajo'))
input (var_numero)
```

Answer (score 0):

print ("Intento 1: ") var_numero = int(input()) print(var_Dato1)

Te comparto un codigo, con algo similar a lo que creo que queres hacer, espero que te sirva y si es así, házmelo saber?

```
    # Ingresar 10 numeros por teclado y sumarlos con While
varIncre = 1
suma = 0
while varIncre <= 10:
    num = int(input("Ingrese el " + str(varIncre) + "º valor:")) 
    suma = suma + num
    varIncre += 1
print("El resultado de la suma es", suma)
print("Fin del programa")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NombreLocalInsertar, EcuacionLocalInsertar = input(f"Ingrese el 'NOMBRE Y ECUACIÓN DEL LOCAL {NumeroLocalInsertar} a INSERTAR (separados por un espacio)': ").split()
```

o

```
NombreLocalInsertar, EcuacionLocalInsertar = input(f"Ingrese el 'NOMBRE Y ECUACIÓN DEL LOCAL {NumeroLocalInsertar} a INSERTAR (separados por una coma)': ").split(",")
```

listado de variables a ingresar separados por comas = input(f"escriba lo que quiera y entre corchete si pone {Otra variable} ").split()